# Help starting ML project in pythin(novice)

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

I am starting a machine learning project (for fun!), but I am not sure where to start from... I am fairly new to ML so any hints are appreciated.

I have a relatively large data-set where each input is a list of roughly 300 integers (mainly zeros). The output is a list of 20ish integers. The goal is to predict the output given a random input (obviously). And I am not sure what is the best method for that. I have started reading a bit into neural networks which seem like it could be a good way to solve such problem, but there seems to be a whole range of different activation etc. (not sure how it's actually called) so I am not really sure what to do.

Any hints on what direction to look into?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So for each sample you have 20 different values (targets) which you want to predict?

Comment: Yes, for each sample I'll have an output of 20 values (integers, most of them 0), and I want to be able to predict this output for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have *several output columns* (targets), you have a limited choice of models since most models predict *one output column*. See the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) for a good overview. In essence you deal with a multioutput problem.

The sklearn models for regression simply aim at predicting each output separately. The `RegressionChain` trys to successively predict one target value after another, taking the previous prediction into account. From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-regression):

> **Multioutput regression** support can be added to any regressor with
> MultiOutputRegressor. This strategy consists of fitting one regressor
> per target. Since each target is represented by exactly one regressor
> it is possible to gain knowledge about the target by inspecting its
> corresponding regressor. As MultiOutputRegressor fits one regressor
> per target it can not take advantage of correlations between targets.
>
> **Regressor chains** (see RegressorChain) is analogous to ClassifierChain
> as a way of combining a number of regressions into a single
> multi-target model that is capable of exploiting correlations among
> targets.

If you want to try neural nets, you can use Keras' "functional API" which allows you to define several outputs (columns). Find a [minimal example here](https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/keras_multitarget_functionalAPI.py). In a nutshell you need to define some input (the $X$ matrix, aka the explanatory variables) and you need to define *all of the outputs* separately. Inputs and outputs can be feeded into the model definition and the model `fit` statement as shown below.

```
# Input and model architecture
Input_1=Input(shape=(13, ))
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(Input_1)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)
x = Dense(8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.05))(x)

# Outputs
out1 = Dense(1)(x)
out2 = Dense(1)(x)

# Compile/fit the model
model = Model(inputs=Input_1, outputs=[out1,out2])
model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss = 'mse')

# Add actual data here in the fit statement
model.fit(train_data, [train_targets,train_targets2], epochs=500, batch_size=4, verbose=0, validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll read more into this. This definitely helps!